# Two different WordPress, two different user accounts, one session

Tags: php, wordpress, session-cookies

```
localhost/wp1/user/a
localhost/wp2/user/a
```

Both users are copies of each other. Their passwords and e-mail addresses are the same. But they are in different WordPress, different database and different server.

My goal is (of course, a hypothesis) that WordPress user sessions are hosted as "`Cookies`" in the internet browser.

So, can it not automatically carry session information when the two brothers navigate between the sites without deleting the user's session in the internet browser?

There must be a way to do this because when a set of cookies that they give to the cookies match, they can automatically access their account when they switch from "`wp1`" to "`wp2`".

Comment: Perhaps this helps: [How to change cookie name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/202009).

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not give a proper example. This is not a domain network. So it doesn't work like a classic multisite. Different domains and servers.

Comment: You're going to have to find a way to share the data, either with REST API or by accessing the database by setting a mysql host.